# How to set crossorigin to the tag of dynamic imports script by webpack?

Tags: webpack

I need to set `crossorigin="anonymous"` to all  tag, included dynamic imports by webpack. How do I add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to script tags of dynamic imports by webpack?

Comment: Webpack (which I assume uses a near-default configuration, as you did not include it in your question) creates a bundled JS file. This JS file is then included with a `script` tag in an HTML file. You need to find your HTML file and add the `crossorigin` attribute.

Comment: I mean the dynamic import modules, Like this:
`private loadModule() {
    return import(/* webpackChunkName: 'MyModule' */'../mydule');
  }`
I think this bundle not included in a HTML file.And no webpack config to set the crossorigin attribute of it.

Comment: Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [the runtime conditionally sets the `<script crossorigin>` attribute](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.44.2/lib/web/JsonpMainTemplate.runtime.js#L25), where `$crossOriginLoading$` is [defined from the `crossOriginLoading` option](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.44.2/lib/web/JsonpMainTemplatePlugin.js#L592-L595).

See also: [`output.crossOriginLoading`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputcrossoriginloading)